# Updating group in codeigniter ion auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am new to codeigniter ion auth and applied it in a project. Everything works fine by following the [documentation](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/). While exploring, I noticed that when I update/edit any user data, it throws no error but the users_groups not updated.

Code:

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');

$data = array(
  'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
  'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
  'group' => array($this->input->post('group_id')),
  'active' => $this->input->post('active')
  );

$result = $this->ion_auth->update($id, $data);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ion_auth->update` method you can update only the user attributes stored in the users table, you cannot modify the user group.
(internally it queries the columns from users table and update only those parameters which are valid attributes of the user)
To modify user group you need to do:

```
$user_id = 123;
$group_id = 3;// let's say 3 is the ID of the 'publisher' user group

// to remove the user (#ID:123) from the 'publisher' group call this:
$this->ion_auth->remove_from_group($group_id, $user_id);
// to remove the user (#ID:123) from all of the assigned groups call this:
$this->ion_auth->remove_from_group(false, $user_id);

// to add the user (#ID:123) to the 'publisher' group call this:
$this->ion_auth->add_to_group($group_id, $user_id);
```

Comment: Good explanation @Zaragoli